# Google Maps Data Layer issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-maps, react-hooks

I am currently struggling quite a bit with the Google Maps react API and the Google Maps documentation. My aim is to render a polygon on the map and do all kinds of manipulation. So far, this is what I came up with.

I can render the GeoJson I receive from my backend on the map without a problem. Further, I can identify a vertexPoint and then show a menu to perform a delete on that vertex point. That works fine. My polygon gets updated immediately. I see the changes on the map and when I log my polygon variable that's also there.

The issue is with my onSave. It appears that it fires console.logs like "hello" correctly each time my mouse is up, but the save from the new geojson structure isn't being passed. I have tested, if the callback works, and it is indeed working, but it only updates the polygon after firing a second time.

That's why I am here for help. Maybe someone can come up with a quick idea while glancing over my code. As I am no expert on this matter, I would also general feedback on the overall handling. I feel that can be also improved.

```
export function MapComponents() {
  const t = useTranslations();
  const { fieldDataV2, setPolygon, polygon } = useFieldDetailsContext();
  const { map } = useLayoutProvider();
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const currentPolyCoordinates = polygon?.geometry?.coordinates;
  const currentFeature = map?.data.getFeatureById('test');

  const area =
    (currentPolyCoordinates && calculateArea(currentPolyCoordinates)) ||
    fieldDataV2?.boundary?.properties?.area;

  const setFeatureStyle = (
    feature: google.maps.Data.Feature,
  ): google.maps.Data.StyleOptions => {
    return {
      fillOpacity: feature.getProperty('fillOpacity') as number, // Set fill opacity
      fillColor: feature.getProperty('fillColor') as string, // Set fill color for the polygon
      strokeColor: feature.getProperty('color') as string, // Set stroke color based on the 'color' property
      strokeWeight: feature.getProperty('strokeWeight') as number,
      zIndex: feature.getProperty('zIndex') as number, // Set stroke weight as needed
      editable: true,
      clickable: true,
    };
  };

  const contentString = `<div
                            id="context-menu-delete-icon" style={{cursor: "pointer"}}
                          >Löschen</div`;

  const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    ariaLabel: 'Delete-Menu',
    content: contentString,
    disableAutoPan: true,
  });

  // This useEffect handles the initial drawing of the polygon on the map
  useEffect(() => {
    if (map) {
      // Add GeoJSON boundary data to the map
      fieldDataV2 && map.data.addGeoJson(fieldDataV2?.boundary);
      fieldDataV2 && setPolygon(fieldDataV2.boundary);
      // Set style for the added feature
      map.data.setStyle(setFeatureStyle);
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [map, fieldDataV2]);

  const onEdit = (event: google.maps.PolyMouseEvent) => {
    const clickedPoint = event.latLng;
    const lngLatArray = clickedPoint && [
      clickedPoint.lng(),
      clickedPoint.lat(),
    ];

    // Check if the clicked point matches any polygon vertices and their lenght is greater then 3
    const isMatch =
      currentPolyCoordinates &&
      lngLatArray &&
      isPointInsideArrays(currentPolyCoordinates, lngLatArray);
    // Open the info window for deletion if there are enough points and we have a vertix match
    if (isMatch) {
      infowindow.open({ map });
      infowindow.setPosition(clickedPoint);
      infowindow.open({ map: map, shouldFocus: false });
      const coordinatesToWorkWith =
        lngLatArray &&
        currentPolyCoordinates &&
        removeFirstPointFromArray(lngLatArray, currentPolyCoordinates);
      // Remove the matched point and format the result for geometry modification
      const filteredAndConvertedCoordinates =
        coordinatesToWorkWith &&
        lngLatArray &&
        filterAndConvertCoordinates(coordinatesToWorkWith, lngLatArray);
      // Add a handler to the infowindow as soon as it gets domready
      google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function () {
        const contextDeleteMenu = document.getElementById(
          'context-menu-delete-icon',
        );
        const infowindowDefaultCloseIcon =
          document.getElementsByClassName('gm-ui-hover-effect');
        if (infowindowDefaultCloseIcon instanceof HTMLCollection) {
          const infoWindowCloseX = infowindowDefaultCloseIcon[0] as HTMLElement;
          infoWindowCloseX.style.display = 'none';
        }
        if (contextDeleteMenu) {
          contextDeleteMenu.style.cursor = 'pointer';
          //Close the infowindow and set the new geometrie to the feature
          contextDeleteMenu.addEventListener('click', () => {
            infowindow.close();
            filteredAndConvertedCoordinates &&
              currentFeature?.setGeometry(
                new google.maps.Data.Polygon(filteredAndConvertedCoordinates),
              );
            currentFeature?.toGeoJson((data) => {
              setPolygon(data as GeoJsonFeaturePolygon);
              setText(JSON.stringify(data) + counter);
            });
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };

  const onSave = () => {
    currentFeature?.toGeoJson((data) => {
      setPolygon(data as GeoJsonFeaturePolygon);
      setText(JSON.stringify(data) + counter);
      setCounter(counter + 1);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (map) {
      // Close the info window anytime a user clicks anywhere on the map
      const mapClickHandler = google.maps.event.addListener(
        map,
        'click',
        () => {
          infowindow.close();
        },
      );

      // Handles click events on vertices
      const vertexClickHandler = map.data.addListener('click', onEdit);

      // Update the polygon to the state and remove the infowindow

      const saveGeometryHandler = map.data.addListener('mouseup', onSave);

      // Cleanup function removes all handlers to prevent multiple initiations on re-renders
      return () => {
        mapClickHandler.remove();
        vertexClickHandler.remove();
        saveGeometryHandler.remove();
      };
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [map, polygon]);
```

Comment: Hi can you please explain further as to what the `onSave` does and what's wrong with it? I don't see your `useFieldContext` being defined anywhere which is where the `setPolygon` that I'm assuming the issue is coming from, is that right? I'd suggest that you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that the community could help you better.

Comment: I actually found the issue. My Event fires correctly and at the time of the event is beeing fired the internal data from google isn't updated jet. That was the issue. To work around that I use a debounce now to fire the event with a nanosecond delay and voila, its enough time for google to update the state of the data layer and I can pass that new state back to my context.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and a way to solve the problem. My call onSave was supposed to grab the data from the data layer object and pass that to my polygon, that was held in the state. The issue was, that google didn't update the data layer while I was doing my mousup, but afterwards. So, I used a debounce set to 1 nanosecond to actually grab the updated state. Everything works fine.